# How to subtract two query result in XQuery in Oracle XML database?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle11g, xquery, xquery-sql

I have following xml file in a oracle XML table. I know very basic of XQuery and XML table. I wondered what are the possible solutions to find all the cities not visited by specific vehicle (registration number).

I was thinking of first I need a "for loop" to save name of all cities and then another "for loop" I must check if that city was visited by vehicle. Is there any way to subtract name of cities visited by specific vehicle from list of all the cities.

> (name of all cities) - (cities visited by vehicle) = (cities have not
>   visited by vehicle)

Here is my XML file (I don't have list of cities):

```
  <trips>
  <trip driver="d2345" vehicle="PKR856" date="12-DEC-2007">
    <from>London</from>
    <to>Newcastle</to>
    <through stop="1">Leicester</through>
    <through stop="2">Nottingham</through>
    <time>1</time>
  </trip>
  <trip driver="d6767" vehicle="UUQ007" date="10-MAY-2008">
    <from>Paris</from>
    <to>Rome</to>
    <through stop="1">Lyon</through>
    <through stop="2">Milan</through>
    <time>15</time>
  </trip>
  <trip driver="d2345" vehicle="PKR856" date="14-DEC-2007">
    <from>Paris</from>
    <to>Amsterdam</to>
    <through stop="2">Brussel</through>
    <through stop="1">Mons</through>
    <time>4</time>
  </trip>
</trips>
```

**I tried**

This is the list of all cities:

```
for $form in /transport/trips/trip/from 
for $to in /transport/trips/trip/to
return 
    <result>
           {$from/text()} 
           {$to/text()} 
    </result>
```

List of cities visited by specific vehicle:

```
for $c in /transport/trips/trip/
 where (data ($c/@ vehicle)=""PKR856"") 
    <result2>
           {$c/from/text()}             
           {$c/to/text()}
    </result2>
```

I appreciate if anyone can help me to subtract these lists.

Comment: Please make sure to post valid code, there are several syntactic problems in your last code block.

Answer (score 1):

Given you have the cities as sequences of strings, use a predicate together with the set-semantics of `=` to filter all visited cities:

```
let $cities := ("Munich", "Berlin", "Hamburg")
let $visited := ("Munich", "Frankfurt")
return $cities[not(. = $visited)]
```

Which will return the cities Berlin and Hamburg.

`=` returns true, if any element on the left side (here: always one city) matches any element on the right side (all visited cities). Realize `$cities[. != $visited]` thus would return something else: `!=` yields true if any value on the left side does not match any value on the right side.

Answer (score 1):

This can even be done solely in XPath. In the following snippet, `$driver-cities` will select all names of cities one particular vehicle has visited. If your processor does not support the `/(element, another-element)` syntax, you can also use the union operator, i.e. `/trips/trip[@vehicle="PKR856"]/from | /trips/trip[@vehicle="PKR856"]/to`.

It then selects all cities, which are not in the sequence of `$driver-cities` as already explained in Jens answer.

```
let $driver-cities := /trips/trip[@vehicle="PKR856"]/(from, to, through)/string()
return /trips/trip/(from, to)/string()[not(. = $driver-cities)]
```

Comment: I am getting an internal error in oracle when I added [not(. = $driver-cities)]